# Error converting Ipython Notebook

Tags: ipython

I have two ipynb files in two folders. Once converts no problem, the other wont convert. Am I doing something wrong? I am converting to html

File 1:

```
cd C:\Users\rcreedon\Dropbox\GIZSupervisor\DATA\Production_Data\STP_Data\Data_Sets\Wave1\1004
ipython nbconvert 1004ProdData.ipynb --to html
```

A total success

File 2:

```
cd C:\Users\rcreedon\Dropbox\GIZSupervisor\DATA\Production_Data\STP_Data\Data_Sets\Wave1\1006
ipython nbconvert 1006prodData.ipynb --to html
```

A Horrid failure.

Error message looks like this

> C:\Users\rcreedon\Dropbox\GIZSupervisor\DATA\Production_Data\STP_Data\Data_Sets
>   Wave1\1006>ipython nbconvert 1006ProdData.ipynb --to html
>   [NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\Users\rcreedon\.ipython\pro
>   ile_default'
>   [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook 1006ProdData.ipynb to html
>   [NbConvertApp] Support files will be in 1006ProdData_files\
>   [NbConvertApp] Loaded template html_full.tpl
>   [NbConvertApp] ERROR | Error while converting '1006ProdData.ipynb'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line
>   00, in convert_notebooks
>       output, resources = exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=res
>   urces)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py",
>   line 289, in from_filename
>       return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(f, 'json'), resources=resource
>   ,**kw)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py",
>   line 260, in from_notebook_node
>       output = self.template.render(nb=nb_copy, resources=resources)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in rend
>   r
>       return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 742, in hand
>   e_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   tml_full.tpl", line 1, in top-level template code
>       {%- extends 'html_basic.tpl' -%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   tml_basic.tpl", line 1, in top-level template code
>       {%- extends 'display_priority.tpl' -%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   keleton\display_priority.tpl", line 1, in top-level template code
>       {%- extends 'null.tpl' -%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   keleton\null.tpl", line 26, in top-level template code
>       {%- block body -%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   tml_full.tpl", line 62, in block "body"
>       {{ super() }}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   keleton\null.tpl", line 29, in block "body"
>       {%- block any_cell scoped -%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   keleton\null.tpl", line 76, in block "any_cell"
>       {%- block headingcell scoped-%}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\exporters..\templates\
>   tml_basic.tpl", line 64, in block "headingcell"
>       {{ ("#" * cell.level + cell.source) | replace('\n', ' ') | strip_math_space
>   | markdown2html | strip_files_prefix | add_anchor }}
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\filters\markdown.py", l
>   ne 55, in markdown2html
>       return pandoc(source, 'markdown', 'html', extra_args=['--mathjax'])
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\utils\pandoc.py", line
>   4, in pandoc
>       "http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html"
>   PandocMissing: The command 'pandoc -f markdown -t html --mathjax' returned an e
>   ror: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Please check that pandoc is installed:
>   http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html

Comment: Do both notebooks have markdown and heading cells? Is it possible that you provide us with the not working notebook (or better a stripped down version)?

Comment: Yes, you were right, the devil was in the raw text and heading files. Pandoc was having trouble, I had it installed since forever, but for some reason it needed a breath of life to handle this file. I cant explain quite why

Comment: The raw text cells are passed without touching, hence these should not create any troubles. The heading cells are passed through pandoc, which lead to the error you posted. Can you post the heading which produces this error?

Comment: actually i didnt do any editing, i simply went intothe ms power shell, confirmed that pandoc was installed (which it was), and then did the same again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is still active or not, but a very similar problem was solved for me by adding the cabal binary path (ex `$HOME/.cabal/bin`) to bash `$PATH`.